# Simplest way to limit user's ability to modify fields in a domain object?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

In a RESTful Spring MVC app, what is the most efficient way to limit user's ability to update domain objects?

Imagine a movie service with the following url: "service/movie/id". There are 2 groups of users, admins and basic users.

While admins can use PUT request to update all the properties of a movie DTO, basic users may only update a subset of them.

What is the best way to implement this with spring security?

I have considered having separate urls for admins and basic users, but that seems inelegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@PreAuthorize` annotation for checking roles. Check it out if it's what you need.
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-pre-post-annotations

**UPDATE**
You can use `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')")` for multiple roles.

Comment: Looked into that, but it seems to be limited to just checking if user has the permission to run a method or not. I'm really looking for a "if/else"-solution.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a very simple way to achieve this, but it may not be the best solution: In my controller methods I can simply find out user's role etc. with:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

And then route it to a service method specific to user's role.